# Create a Login Role in order to view unpublished content

Tags: users

I need to create a **role** where an authenticated user can log in and see pages that were unpublished to the outside world. Is there **documentation** that explains the best way to set this up?

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There's the administer content permission you can set for a role, but that is a pretty broad permission. It sounds like you're looking for [View Unpublished](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) module. It even has such a use case on the project page:

> Used in concert with the [Override node options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module, you can give
>   specific roles the ability to publish/unpublish certain node types
>   without giving those roles administrative access to all nodes. A
>   tutorial for this use case exists here:
>   http://brightbacon.com/blog/drupal/allowing-node-publishingunpublishing-...